# Error while loading a js as static resource in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have an static resource name CustomHelperJS, which is a javascript and is public. In my application i have this :

```
 <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
     <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS202_HV1 + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'}"
              scripts="{!$Resource.CustomHelperJS}" />

   <aura:dependency resource="c:LC01_GeneratePlainLayout"/>
```

when I include this app in my vf page and load it, the css apply well, but i obtain an error on my page :

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined throws at https://xxxoffice--agsdev--c.cs5.visual.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8PUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:499:85
 </aura:application>
```

My js file has not been loaded. I cannot refer to any js method i defined in that file. It gives me error, stating that the method does not exist.

Has anyone encounter problems with referencing a js file stored as a single static resource in lightning components ?

Comment: Does your component run properly in a standalone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to load correctly. In fact it loaded my JS file correctly , but my JS file started with the script tag inside it. So the lightning component didn't like it :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    ......
    .....
    ......
 </script>
```

Comment: i can't accept it right now....i only can tomorrow...